# Windows 2008 files corrupted with Nulls starting on 64K boundries

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am looking for possible causes of file corruption.

I have some files that are 10s to 100s of MB in size that have gotten corrupted.  Large chunks of the file have been overwritten with NULLs starting on some 64K boundry.

These files are not updated, they were written originally to local disk and then copied by a program using the CopyFile api to the SAN disk where they get read but never updated.

I expect that this is due to hardware errors but am not getting any error when reading the file (Just the nulls instead of the data that was there.)

Comment: I think you need to have a long chat with your storage admin.

Comment: We have but they are trying do deny that it could be them.

Comment: Uh... OK.  Is anyone actually buying that?  "The files, which reside on your storage, are all effed up starting on some 64K boundary.  Earn your paycheck and figure out why."

Comment: This is a case of outsourced hardware management.  So they are claiming that the files must have been created with the NULLs.

Answer (score 2):

A few things I'd investigate would be:

- Does your storage do zero page reclamation? If so, what size chunks do they work with? Does that line up with the damage? Not a smoking gun, but a definite clue.
- Is the server a VM? What's the hypervisor? What are the settings for the virtual disk? Do you do any thin provisioning at that layer?
- Does the backup software have access to this data read-only, or read-write? Have you looked in the logs for the software?
- Do you know when the corruption occurred? Can you go back in your backups to a point before it happened? If so, this is the time you want to be scouring the logs of anything that might be a suspect.

It's really difficult to solve this forensically, but I'd see if you can find a way to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I will offer this as a potential answer:

Has anyone started a large file restore from your back-up utility?

I saw something similar to this after a tech attempted to restore an entire network share.

Do you see any commonality among who owns the corrupted files?